Can't seem to achieve anywhere near my GPU global memory bandwidth in OpenCL
Using opencl on my AMD GPU, I've only been able to achieve 4% (15 GB/sec) of the GPU global-memory bandwidth reported by clpeak (375 GB/sec).
Before resigning myself to this, I want to make sure I'm not guilty of some newbie mistake (ex. I learned the hard way that the CL_MEM_SVM_FINE_GRAIN_BUFFER flag leads to a 40x slowdown).
To put the problem in context:  I'm relatively new to opencl and have been trying to perform a certain calculation on my GPU.  This calculation involves a number of unavoidable and essentially random global GPU memory reads/writes within my inner-loop.  Unsurprisingly, these constitute the vast majority of kernel time.  I know that global access is suboptimal, but let's just assume it really is unavoidable here.  [To clarify, when I say "global" I mean on the GPU.  None of the performance I'm referring to involves data xfers between host and GPU.]
I was able to reproduce the performance issue using a simple toy kernel --- which still does no better than 20GB/sec.
kernel void testkernel(__global const ulong *loc,__global uchar *res,__global const uchar *val,__private ulong bsize)
{
    uint n= get_global_id(0);
    ulong i= n*bsize;
    ulong j= i+bsize;
    uchar z= 0;
    for (ulong k=i;k<j;++k)
    {
        ulong l= loc[k];
        ulong l2= loc[l];
        z+= val[l2];
    }
    res[n]= z;
}

bsize is a loop-counter, which I set to 1000.
If nkern denotes the number of kernel instances I will enqueue, then loc and val have sizes nkern*bsize, and res has size nkern.
res is just a result array (one per kernel instance) to prevent the loop from being optimized away.
loc is what emulates random access across my full global memory.  I populated it with random values [0,asize).
val is just another array to add some flavor.  I populated it with random values [0,256).
I did all the randomization, etc in host memory, then copied the arrays to the GPU using clEnqueueSVMMemcpy before enqueueing all the kernel instances.  The GPU memory was allocated using clSVMAlloc with just the CL_MEM_READ_WRITE flag.
I ran this toy kernel with various nkern values (10K, 100K, and 700K), but always get around 20 GB/sec.  [In computing this I count the inner loop as having 17 bytes of bandwidth --- 2 ulongs and a uchar.  I also ran the entire round --- enqueuing and waiting for all nkern instances --- 10 times to get decent statistics.  At nkern=700K, I'm pretty close to the useable memory of my GPU, so this means I'm reading my entire GPU memory 10x.].
For reference, my GPU is an AMD RX 5700XT (a gfx1010 device) with 8GB of global memory arranged in 32 banks and at around 2GhZ.  clpeak reports around 375 GB/sec global bandwidth for floatn (regardless of n).  AMD reports that I have 2304 stream processors (which appear to be arranged in 20 compute units).  I'm using opencl 2.0 (the latest my card supports) and am running on linux with the actual AMD rocm driver --- which is the only one I could get working.
I'm perfectly willing to accept that I'm constrained by the number of memory calls rather than the memory bandwidth, and that 15GB/sec is the best I'll get.  However, I'd like to confirm that this actually is the case before giving up on a potential 25x improvement.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

It's a while since I've done any OpenCL programming, and I never got particularly good at optimising memory bound applications. I also have experienced performance of the same order of magnitude, so I don't think you're doing it wrong or that there's something inherently wrong with your setup.
I put my results down to the following arguments, though I haven't had them confirmed. When you request a long randomly in a buffer, GPUs, like CPUs, don't just fetch those 8 bytes, they fill a whole cache line. On modern x86 CPUs that's 64 bytes, and it might even read ahead more than that. I don't know what it is on your GPU. The quoted bandwidth counts all the data transferred, and not just the few bytes you might need. I don't think you'll be able to get anywhere near a 20x performance improvement, unless you experiment with bigger data requests.
I hope this lays some of your concerns about your program and setup to rest.

I see.  So according to that, I'm actually pulling in 1024+2641000+64 =129088 bytes (since the loc[k] lookup actually benefits from the cache) per kernel instance instead of 171000+64= 17064.    This does give a 7.5 slowdown, which would bring me more in line with expectations (since I wouldn't really expect to achieve the top speed in a practical application).   However, if that is the case, then we effectively have (at 700K kernel instances) 7e5(16+2000)= 1.4e9 actual lookup calls (since loc[k] needs 16 calls for the 1000 lookups due to caching).

With 2304 streamers running at 2GhZ, this gives an effective lookup time operation of 3265 cycles.  On CPUs, it is around 400 cycles.  On the other hand, if that 400 cycle spec assumes caching, then only 1/8 of operations would involve actual memory reads --- so this would be in line with my numbers.  I guess I need to learn more about how this stuff is being done.

Do you happen to know if there's any way to instruct the GPU (via the opencl compiler) that a particular lookup won't benefit from caching?   Maybe there's some sort of pragma or attribute I could tag it with.

Sorry, no. You mean an equivalent to a non-temporal load for the GPU? There might be at the machine level but I'm not aware of a way to do it in OpenCL, though that's not saying much. We're at the limit of my understanding of GPU memory here. If you find out anything interesting or useful about this, please add it to your question or add your own answer. I'd be interested to read it. Of course, there's no guarantee a non-temporal load would be much if any faster, but it wouldn't pollute the cache as much.

I think you're absolutely right about the cause.  I tested my original program and, if I account for the 64 byte cache lines, I get almost exactly the full expected bandwidth.  I also took a look at the clpeak code and their benchmark (the one which produced 360 GB/sec) unsurprisingly does sequential reads.  My own program executes at an effective speed of 200GB/sec taking into account cache lines --- which is quite reasonable given that profiling tells me I/O accounts for around 2/3 of the runtime.  So, it's in the right ballpark of what can be achieved.

Thank you for your insight!  This saves me a lot of potential wasted time trying to optimize the wrong things.
